# Why is my header clickable on ListFragment

Tags: android

I have a ListFragment and in the ListFragment.onViewCreated I have this code:

```
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rowheader, null);
this.getListView().addHeaderView(header);
```

My layout simply have a LinearLayout (horizontal) with four TextView's inside.

Now what I do not understand is that the header receives click events and it also displays the blue overlay/color/thing on the header when it is clicked. How can that be, and can I disable this somehow?

Thank you

Søren

Comment: Pls dont forget to mark as accepted, if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
this.getListView().addHeaderView(header, null, false)
```

instead of

```
this.getListView().addHeaderView(header);
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of Object is the header view?

You might want to see if the view has a `setEnabled()` method, `setClickable()` or `setSelectable()`. You would be able to set that before you add the header view to the list view